# Compojure: access filesystem

Tags: tomcat, clojure, leiningen, compojure, ring

this is my project.clj file:

```
(defproject org.github.pistacchio.deviantchecker "0.9.0"
  :description "A one page application for keeping track of changes on deviantart.com gallieries"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.1"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]
                 [enlive  "1.0.0"]
                 [compojure "0.6.4"]
                 [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.0.0-beta2"]]
  :dev-dependencies [[lein-ring "0.4.6"]]
  :ring {:handler org.github.pistacchio.deviantchecker.core/app}
  :main org.github.pistacchio.deviantchecker.core)
```

and this my routing:

```
(defroutes main-routes
  (GET "/" [] (get-home))
  (GET "/add" [d] (add-gallery d))
  (GET "/delete" [d] (delete-gallery d))
  (GET "/check" [d] (check-gallery d))
  (route/resources "/")
  (route/not-found "Page not found"))
```

I have some web static files in `/resources/public` and I can access them. In the code I also need o access some files on the file system that are located on `/resources/data` and `/resources/tpl`. Using `lein ring` server or `lein run`, the following call works fine

```
(java.io.File. "resources/tpl/home.html")
```

but when packing the application with `lein uberwar` and deploying under Tomcat it fails and I get a FileNotFoundException. Maybe this is because with lein the *current working directory* is the project root while under Tomcat it is Tomcat's bin directory.

For example, I have `/resources/data/data.dat` that gets packed in the war as `/data/data.dat` so either "resources/data/data.dat" doesn't work under Tomcat or "data/data.dat" doesn't work in development.

By the way, what is the proper way of managing this in Compojure? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clojure.java.io/resource` to access resources whether they're on the local file system, or packed in a jar/war:

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])
(io/reader (io/resource "public/some/file.txt")) ; file in resource classpath or $root/resources/public...
```

You probably shouldn't try to load them from a directory, since you can't be sure where the file is going to end up when its deployed from a jar/war (or even if it's on the file system at all, probably).

Comment: hi, thanks for the tip, but this doesn't solve the problem. on development, for example, i have $/resources/data/data.dat that gets packed as $/data/data.dat so either (io/resource "resources/data/data.dat") doesn't work in production or (io/resource "data/data.dat") doesn't work on development.

Comment: ok, it worked. i also had to add  :resource-path "resources/" to project.clj