# How to display an image using Compojure?

Tags: clojure, compojure

This compojure question is twofold!

1. How can I display an image object in a webpage (like a chart I get from Incanter)?
2. How can I display images in the filesystem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For 1., try [Building a Clojure Web application with Incanter, Compojure, and Leiningen](http://data-sorcery.org/2009/11/29/incanter-webapp/).

For 2., try [Compojure: access filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836030/compojure-access-filesystem)